# Adding Tier Pricing Programmatically - Not Showing in Admin

Tags: php, tierprice

I have searched for a week to find the specific solution to my problem maybe one of you can help! It would be very appreciated :)

I have some products with Tier Pricing that I added through the Magento Admin backend manually and it works beautifully.  I am able to update those prices programmatically and the results are amazing!

However here is my problem.  For products with no current tier prices I can't add them programmatically :( I have far too many products and variations to manually go and giev each product 6 tier prices.

Here is some example code:
If I call `var_dump($product->getData('tier_price'))` on an item with one tier.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["price_id"]=>
    string(3) "403"
    ["website_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["all_groups"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["cust_group"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["price"]=>
    string(7) "84.2400"
    ["price_qty"]=>
    string(6) "1.0000"
    ["website_price"]=>
    string(7) "84.2400"
  }
}
```

I created a variable called $standardTierPrices which is:
`$standardTierPrices = array();`
I realize it doesn't have `["price_id"]` but how can I add that if it auto increments and starts whenever created?  Even with me custom setting unique ['price_id'] it still doesn't work I tested it!  I also tried without all_groups and website_price, still no cigar.

```
>$standardTierPrices[0] = array(
    "website_id"  => "0",
    "all_groups" => "0",
    "cust_group" => "8",
    "price" => "1950.0000",
    "price_qty" => "1.0000",
    "website_price" => "1950.0000"
);
```

Now I call

```
$product->unsTierPrice()->save()->setTierPrice($standardTierPrices)->save();
```

If I run `$product->getData('tier_prices')`
I can see the attribute gets added but it is not updated in the Admin panel
I want the tier prices to show in the admin panel not just the attributes.
Here is a specific picture of what I want and what I get.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWNSc.jpg

TLDR:: I want to programmatically create this for an item -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5QaN.jpg, a tier pricing in the Admin Panel

From a product that starts with no tier pricing.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing `all_groups` and `website_price` and using integers or floats unless you need strings for the prices. Try this:

```
$adminId = Mage::app()->getWebsite(false)->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStoreId();
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123)
    ->setTierPrice(array(
        array(
            'cust_group' => 8,
            'price' => 1950,
            'price_qty' => 1,
            'website_id' => $adminId
        ),
        array(
            'cust_group' => 9,
            'price' => 1900,
            'price_qty' => 1,
            'website_id' => $adminId
        ),
    ))
    ->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but still not working :( 
I took out all_groups and website_price it saves to the product's attribute ['tier_price'] still but doesn't show up in the Admin Magento section.

Comment: Can you provide more code samples, and/or test with with the smallest code possible to rule out other issues? Also, which version of Magento?

Comment: Sure Tyler! Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

I'll update the question to have simpler examples :)

Answer (score 1):

Awesome so I got it working! If any of you have questions leave them in the comments and I'll do my best to help you out too!

So I had to add a special variable

$standardTierPrices = array();
$adminId = Mage::app()->getWebsite(false)->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStoreId();

> $standardTierPrices[0] = array(
>       "website_id"  => "$adminId",
>       "cust_group" => "8",
>       "price" => "1950.0000",
>       "price_qty" => "1.0000",
>   );

By using the admin ID it matched it and correctly added it to the backend and the Admin Panel.